# ElasticSearch Tire two field conditional filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filter, elasticsearch, tire

I'm doing a mutli-index query With Tire and rails 3 and I want to filter out Venues who have approved => false so I need some sort of combo filter.

Here is the query

```
query = params[:q]
from = params.delete(:from)
size = params[:size] || 25
Tire.search(
  [Venue.index_name, 
   Performer.index_name, User.index_name], load: true) do |s|
    s.query do
      string(query, fields: [:_all, :name, :title], use_dis_max: true)
    end
    s.from from if from
    s.size size if size
  end.results.to_a
```

This line removes all Performers and Users because they don't have an :approved field.

```
s.filter(:term, :approved => true )
```

And this line obviously removes all non-venues which is no good.

```
s.filter(:term, { :approved => true, :index_name => 'venues'} )
```

Any ideas besides adding an approved: true field to all Users and Performers?  I think something like this is what I want conceptually:

```
s.filter(:term, :approved => true, :if => {:index_name => 'venues'} )
```

**EDIT** Thanks to Mallox I was able to find the Should construct but I'm still struggling to implement it Tire.  It seems like the below code should work but it return no results on any query.  I also remove the "{:terms => { :index_name => ["performers", "users"]}}," to make sure it wasn't my use of index name or multiple lines of query that was the problem and still no luck.  Can anybody shed some light on how to do this in Tire?

```
      s.filter(:bool, :should => [ 
        {:terms => { :index_name => ["performers", "users"]}},
        {:term => { :approved => true}},
      ] )
```

Answer (score 3):

So i have little knowledge about Ruby and Tire, but the ElasticSearch query that you want to build would be based on a bool filter, that contains some "should" entries (which would translate into inclusive OR).

So in your case something along the lines of:

```
"filter" : {
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [
            {
                "terms" : { "_type" : ["Performers","Users"] }
            },
            {
                "term" : { "approved" : true }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Take a look at the documentation here, maybe that'll help:
:http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm going to upvote it because it pointed me to the should construct which is definitely what I need.  However it appears (I hope I'm wrong) that Tire has some dodgy support for multiple nested should boolean clauses.  Hopefully somebody can help me get it working with Tire.